# Is it possible to renew sessions in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, session, asp.net-core, .net-core

In order to prevent sessions fixation attacks I would like to generate a new session ID after a user has authenticated themselves.
So far I have not found any way to do this with [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session v2.2.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-3.0). As far as I can tell, the non-Core version doesn't support this either.

Is there an API or method that I have missed?

Pointers to other middlewares with these features are also appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Session fixation doesn't apply to the way ASP.NET Core handles sessions. The cookie that's sent doesn't contain the session id: only a session key. The key is persistent and intended to always be valid. The server independently decides whether or not to restore an existing session or create a new one (i.e. the session id).